# Parse error syntax error unexpected 'foreach' (t_foreach)

Tags: php

This is my code. I want to load data from a database, not an array. I want it as a string and put it in PDF. I want to make a form like this:

First name : "load it from data base"
Name : "load it from data base"

```
<?php 

session_start();

require('../fpdf17/fpdf.php');

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pfe', 'root', '');
$query = $pdo-> prepare("SELECT IdC,Nom,Prenom,CIN,CNE FROM candidats where    IdC = 1 ");
$query->execute();



$pdf=new FPDF();

$pdf->Addpage();


$pdf->SetFont('Times','I','20');
$pdf->SetXY(5,35);
$pdf->Cell(163,10,utf8_decode("Centre d'Etudes Doctorales Sciences et  Applications"),"B","1","L");

$pdf->SetFont('Times','BI','25');
$pdf->SetXY(10,50);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,utf8_decode("Fiche de Candidature à l'Inscription en  "),"0","1","L");

$pdf->SetFont('Times','BI','25');
$pdf->SetXY(15,60);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,utf8_decode("1ére Année de Doctorat(2015- 2016)"),"0","1","L");

$pdf->SetFont('Times','BI','10');
$pdf->SetXY(20,60);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,utf8_decode(foreach($query->fetchAll() as $key=>$value){   print $value['IdC'] ;}),"0","1","L");

$pdf->output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong romove last space from your query after `IdC = 1`

```
$query = $pdo-> prepare("SELECT IdC,Nom,Prenom,CIN,CNE FROM candidats where    IdC = 1 ");
```

The query would be

```
$query = $pdo-> prepare("SELECT IdC,Nom,Prenom,CIN,CNE FROM candidats where IdC = 1");
```